# DLL interface parameter mangled for debug version but not for release version c++ visual studio

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2019

I have a library packaged as a DLL and I am strange behavior when I access a simple function from calling program (both in c++ and using visual studio 2019).
DLL header and function:

```
bool libvpop_EXPORT GetLibVersion(string& version);

bool GetLibVersion(string& version)
{
    version = VPOPLIB_VERSION;
    return true;
}
```

Calling code:

```
bool VPLIB_Return;

string verstring = "XX";
VPLIB_Return = GetLibVersion(verstring);
```

This works fine in the release version of the calling program but in the debug version, the verstring parameter appears to be completely mangled (i.e. verstring = "\x11ta\x2") between the call and the target function GetLibVersion.  I have closely inspected the project properties between the debug and release versions, setting them equal and back to no avail.  Just wondering if anyone has any insight as to why parameter passing would be different between a debug and release build.  One other point, this DLL library has many other functions which appear to working just fine.

Comment: Are you mixing debug and release modules (exe / dlls) as the layout of `std::string` (and other `std` objects) may differ between debug and release?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/iterator-debug-level?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from Richard Critten, I now understand what was going on.  My dll library was compiled as a release configuration.  The release configuration of my calling program worked fine it appears because the std::string objects were compatible but the debug configuration of my calling program must have been using debug versions of std.  The fix required making 2 changes to the Project Properties for the debug config:  1) change C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library from Multi-threaded Debug DLL to Multi-threaded DLL and 2) changed the C/C++->Preprocessor Definitions to include NDEBUG instead of _DEBUG.  I did not realize that the std library had debug and nodebug versions.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)